# Is there any way to migrate open graph settings across applications?

Tags: facebook, migration, facebook-opengraph

We have multiple Facebook applications that would ideally share the same open graph settings -- we have one for each of our own dev environments, one for staging, and one for production. Is there an easy way to migrate our action types, object types, and aggregations across each app?

The current manual process is just not cutting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to do this. There hasn't been a way to transfer app settings from app to app so I would imagine the same for Open Graph app settings.

Comment: The correct answer, but no upvotes because it is not a popular answer.