# Multiple deployment environments (production/staging/etc) and Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook-graph-api, deployment

I'm looking for a "best practice" kind of answer with regard to Facebook Apps and staging/production environment. Instinctively, I've provided each environment with its own Facebook App, complete with its own ID and secret. It appears ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016749/is-there-any-way-to-migrate-open-graph-settings-across-applications), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469482/migrating-fb-open-graph-actions-objects-and-aggregations-from-dev-to-production) and through extensive Googling) that it's simply not possible to share OG configuration across apps, so I've been copying application settings across environments (icon, requested permissions and texts, etc). It's been a pain and ugly, but I've lived with it.

Alas, with the introduction of opengraph actions, this isn't funny anymore - much more to copy and everything has to go through the approval process. Is there no better way to do this? A coworker suggested we simply share the same app across all environments, but I'm apprehensive about that - it means we'll have to share production secrets with the staging environment (I'm not even talking about localhost development environments), and that we'll need to route Facebook traffic to the correct environment somehow (because one Facebook app means one Page Tab URL).

There has to be a better way... no?

Comment: Facebook just now send me a survey titled _What do you think about the Open Graph submission process?_... I told them exactly what I bloody think about it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see there's a feature called "Test Apps" now that seems to fit the bill:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

> Test Apps are like regular apps in that they have their own App ID and independent settings, but they offer a number of advantages for use during pre-production:
>   ...
>   When creating test apps - the settings are copied from your production app so its simple to spinup new apps which mirror your production app's settings

It's working for me so far.

Answer (score 5):

I asked practically the same question at a breakout session at F8 last year.  Creating multiple apps is the best practice.  They are aware that it is an inconvenience, especially with the open graph objects and actions.  They did however mention the possibility of setting up apps in the future via the API, but I am still waiting for this.  Until then, it's a manual process.

Comment: But submitting open graph actions for each app separately sucks, as Yaniv says it isn't funny anymore. There has got to be a better way.